# Dominoes initial draw in a double-6 set includes exactly 5 of one suit

Tags: probability

The total number of 7-draw combinations is $28 \choose 7$ which equals 1,184,040.

To calculate the number of 7-draw combinations that include exactly 5 of the same suit, my logic is there are 7 suits, choose 1. For the suit selected, there are 6 remaining dominoes and I need to choose 4. Of the 21 dominoes not of the suit selected, I need to choose 2.

$7 \choose 1$ multiplied by $6 \choose 4$ multiplied by $21 \choose 2$ = 7 x 15 x 210 = 22,050

22,050 / 1,184,040 = 1.862268166%

Is this correct? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need $\binom{7}{5}$ when choosing five dominoes of the selected suit. (Selecting a suit does not include choosing a domino of that suit.)

Comment: Thank you! The correct answer is 2.607175433%.